# how to import Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

[image]
[image]

I saw some examples,bu it don't solve my problem!

Any help will be Appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDNs, or content delivery networks, are code files hosted on the web that you can include in your project. Using a CDN is the fastest way to get set up with Bootstrap.

Find a CDN for Bootstrap. MaxCDN hosts the latest version:

```
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Simply include the code above in your HTML head element and you will be good to go!

Another option is to download your own copy of Bootstrap and integrate it into your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have the files locally in the static folder, you can just use them in the html templates, for example:

```
 {% load static %}
 <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem ,the version of the Django is 1.11. I check the Django website,it told me I must build files like this and set setting.py like this.But thanks for all of you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMjcx.png)